# Data lookup in Talend

Tags: sql, excel, talend

I have a task to copy data from excel to sql table.
One of the column in my sql table is a foreign key so I need to do a database lookup to fill in this column along with copying data from excel sheet.

[image: Here's a screenshot of my Talend job.]

[image: And my Mapping]

My input table has 2 rows with state as 'ma' and 'tx'.
My excel input too has 2 rows with state as 'ma' and 'tx'.

My job is running but my final output table has repetitive columns.
It has 4 columns with state as 'ma','tx','ma','tx'.

How do I manage this?

Answer (score 0):

you can set `state` as key in the output, or you can add a `tUniqRow` component after the tmap.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the join type in your tMap to `Inner Join`. You can do this by clicking on the wrench on the left hand side and then selecting the join type. It defaults to an outer (left) join but it seems like what you really want here is an inner join.